# Why do I get "no overload method takes 0 arguments" error?

Tags: c#, asp.net, jqgrid, jqgrid-asp.net

I get "no overload method 'getStarDropdown' takes 0 arguments" error using the following code.

How can i resolve this? As i am a newbie!

Kindly help thanks :)

First Class :

```
public DataTable getStarDropdown(int starID)
    {
        try
        {
            DataTable dtStar = null;
            CommonDAL obj = new CommonDAL();
            DataSet dsAll = obj.getStarEntity(starID);

            if (dsAll != null)
                dtStar = dsAll.Tables[1];
            return dtStar;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string msg = ex.Message;

            ExceptionLogger.WriteToLog(hostWebUrl, "CommonDAL", "getAllDropDown()", ex.Message, ex.StackTrace, ExceptionLogger.LOGTYPE.ERROR.ToString());
            return null;
        }

    }
```

Second Class :

```
public static List<Dictionary<string, object>> GetStarData()
    {
        CommonBAL obj = new CommonBAL();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt = obj.getStarDropdown();

        System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
        List<Dictionary<string, object>> rows = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();
        Dictionary<string, object> row;
        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
        {
            row = new Dictionary<string, object>();
            foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
            {
                row.Add(col.ColumnName, dr[col]);
            }
            rows.Add(row);
        }
        return rows;

    }
```

Comment: `obj.getStarDropdown();` you need to pass a starID to this method according to its signature `DataTable getStarDropdown(int starID)` that's what the compiler tells you. It cannot find an overload of this method that takes no arguments because there is only the one that take one int argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the second class, an integer is required when setting a value to dt.

So

```
dt = obj.getStarDropdown(PUT AN INTEGER HERE)
```

Comment: If you don't know what an Integer is here is a link. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/int

Answer (score 1):

Your function expects a parameter of type int

/pass integer value to the function,

```
 dt = obj.getStarDropdown(1);
```

Comment: Some integer as in? Sorry I am new so I need assistance @Sajeetharan

Comment: your getStarDropdown expects a starId, pass the startID